# Could not find package laravel/laravel with version ^9.0

Tags: laravel, installation, project

I want to create a new project with laravel. I wrote the command like this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app
```

However, I got a message like this

```
 Could not find package laravel/laravel with version ^9.0.
```

I have tried with code

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

But I got an error message like this

```
 Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable.
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered a similar situation.
This error is caused by laravel 9.0 requires PHP version >= 8.0.2, please check your PHP version and run again:
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app

Comment: I have checked my php version. It shows version 8.1.12

Comment: please make sure you run composer with php 8.1.12

Comment: ex: php8.1 /usr/local/bin/composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 example-app